# How Do I Build/Submit Apps Build with iOS 14 APIs using Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios14, xcode12

We are doing a round of updates for our apps and would like to go ahead and future proof them for iOS 14 as well. However, Apple isn't accepting binaries built with Xcode 12 beta yet for production (they will accept for Testflight beta testing only), and Xcode 11 doesn't have the iOS 14 SDK/frameworks that we need to build against (like AppTrackingTransparency).

It looks like there are some apps out in the store that are using the AppTrackingTransparency framework though, so I'd like to know what I'm missing.

Comment: No, it's impossible that any apps on the App Store should have been published with the app tracking transparency framework.

Answer (score 2):

try to add the AppTrackingTransparency framework of xcode 12 to xcode 11 and try the summit on the appStore again with xcode 11.

[image]

Comment: How did you accomplish this? Using the same version/build of Xcode I cannot find the AppTrackingTransparency.framework when I try to add it and search for it in the list of frameworks.

Comment: OK I actually see what you mean. I can just fine the framework in the Xcode-beta app and manually add it in Xcode 11. However if you Do Not Embed it the code is not actually there so builds fail. And will apple take an app if I embed and sign it myself or embed it without signing?

Comment: build and run your app on the real device with mode release.
some app crash on iOS 14 beta  when build mode debug .

Comment: @KevinTydlacka Can you please tell how you solved this issue in Xcode 11?, I'm still getting "ld: framework not found AppTrackingTransparency" even when I manually add AppTrackingTransparency.framework from Xcode 12 to the Xcode 11 project

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary now that Apple is accepting apps built with Xcode 12, you can just use Xcode 12 to build/submit now which natively includes the ATT framework